# use boto3 command as a string

Tags: python, boto, boto3

We can use `boto3` package to get the data from mTurk account (or do anything else in AWS). For example:

```
client = boto3.client('mturk')
balance = client.get_account_balance()
```

Is there a way to use boto3 command as a string? Something like:

```
balance = client.get_command('get_account_balance')
```

`get_command` is totally just for illustrative purposes here of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def get_command(client, command):
    return getattr(client, command)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getattr` built-in function:

```
getattr(client, 'get_account_balance')()
```